# How to download BLPAPI using pip install

Tags: blpapi

I am a new Bloomberg Terminal user and I have tried following the instructions [here](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/) to download the Bloomberg API using python. However, when I run the following in the command prompt

```
python -m pip install --index-url=https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple blpapi
```

I get the following error...

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blpapi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for blpapi
Could not fetch URL https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bloomberg.bintray.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pip/simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
```

Could someone please help me download this package to allow me to download data from the Bloomberg API?

Comment: Although I have not been able to fix this issue, I can simply run the BQNT function in the Bloomberg Terminal and that gives me the desired functionality...

Comment: Unfortunately you don't provide details on your platform/setup which makes it difficult to help.

Answer (score 5):

From [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/) site, use:

```
pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi
```

Answer (score 1):

I would install this via `conda`. [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) was designed to help address package management in python where there are various non python dependencies (in this case C++ shared libraries). Try

```py
conda install -c conda-forge blpapi
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey what version of Python were you using via PIP? Reason why Conda works is because the newest available default version is Python 3.7. but with PIP I recall installing Python 3.8 and got same errors as yourself.

The resolution was to install Python 3.7 (make sure to install to path), set the file path to the path variable higher than the existing Python 3.8 so that your CMD uses that version as default, and then suddenly the blpapi install worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. You may not have the C++ compiler needed. You can try to do the followings:

Install Microsoft Visual Studio with the following components

- C++/CLI Support
- VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop
- Visual C++ MFC for x86 and x64
- Visual C++ ATL for x86 and x64

You may have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.x.x Redistributable or any other version on your computer but it is different from "VC++ 2015.3 v14.00" which comes with Visual Studio.