# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blpapi

Tags: python-3.x, pip, blpapi

I'm trying to install blpapi (python 3.7.3) using the steps described in the Bloomberg API library (https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/)

I installed the C++ API (also from the Bloom API library) and copy pasted blpapi3_32.dll and blpapi3_64.dll to their specific folder (C:\blp\DAPI). Basically I just followed the steps described in this page : https://medium.com/@johann_78792/getting-started-with-bloombergs-python-desktop-api-5fd083b4193a

when I excute the command :

```
 python -m pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple/ blpapi
```

I get the error below:

```
ERROR : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blpapi
ERROR : No matching distribution found for blpapi
```

If I'm right, the python version shouldn't be the problem and I upgraded the PIP to the latest version,
I also tried installing blpapi using

```
python -m pip install blpapi
```

I get blpapi-0.0.0 installed successfully (which could be found in Pypi.org), however python doesn't import it giving me this error

```
ImportError: No module named blpapi
```

Any idea of how I can manage these errors would be great.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) package manager which greatly simplifies things. There are many gotchyas, when trying to pip install `blpapi`, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109413/bloomberg-blpapi-install/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590051/how-to-download-blpapi-using-pip-install), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58896429/unable-to-import-blpapi/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716734/blpapi-import-could-not-open-c-sdk-library-very-confused/). Via conda this can be done with

```
conda install -c conda-forge blpapi
```

Comment: Not working in Jan 2023.